# How to find which languages are being used in a given project running on GraalVM?

Tags: devops, graalvm

Say my team is working on a polyglot project where different devs are contributing using various JVM-based *(Scala, Kotlin)* or dynamic languages *(JavaScript, Ruby, Python)* languages. As a Devops engineer I would like to know what types of languages are being used for a given project that gets run/executed with GraalVM.

Is there any support built in GraalVM SDK that I can leverage and hash out a quick script?

Answer (score 1):

JVM based languages are, practically speaking, indistinguishable after they are compiled, i.e. they are all just bytecode.

As far as dynamic languages go, you can check which languages are installed (usign https://www.graalvm.org/truffle/javadoc/org/graalvm/polyglot/Engine.html#getLanguages-- for example) but that does not mean they are all (or any of them) actually used.

To check which languages are actually used during execution, one could develop a Truffle Instrument (https://www.graalvm.org/truffle/javadoc/com/oracle/truffle/api/instrumentation/TruffleInstrument.html) which would, on loading of new sources (https://www.graalvm.org/truffle/javadoc/com/oracle/truffle/api/instrumentation/LoadSourceListener.html), make a note of the language of the source (https://www.graalvm.org/truffle/javadoc/com/oracle/truffle/api/source/Source.html#getLanguage--), allowing one to check at any point which Truffle languages have been in use thus far.